# Removing element from vector : Invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to remove a particular element from a vector, but when I use the erase(remove) functions, I get this error :

> [...]/v1/algorithm:2139:24: Invalid operands to binary expression ('Component' and 'const Component')

I searched for a solution, defined the == operator, both in the class and outside of the class, but I can't find why it's not working.

Here's the code :

```
void OGWindow::deleteSquare( Component *squPtr )
{
    cout << "Deleting component " << squPtr->getIndex() << endl;
    compVector.erase(std::remove(compVector.begin(), compVector.end(), *squPtr), compVector.end());
}
```

Operator == :

```
bool Component::operator==(Component& c){
    return this->getIndex() == c.getIndex();
}
```

The component index is not related to the vector.

Thanks.

EDIT : This operator overload works :

```
bool Component::operator==(const Component& c) const{
    return this->index == c.index;
}
```

Comment: and what is the `compVector` definition?

Comment: @Ap31 std::vector< Component > compVector;
When I comment out the erase line, it compiles and the cout prints the good value.

Answer (score 1):

`std::remove` requires a const reference as a value to compare to. Try introducing some `const` modifiers into your `operator==`:

```
bool Component::operator==(const Component& c) const
```

This will in turn require `Component::getIndex()` to be `const` too of course, so be ready for that.

If you don't want to make your `operator==` const, you can always use `std::remove_if` instead of `std::remove` and use your custom predicate - it can even hold a non-const value and call any method you like.

In general, if it's possible to go with `const`, it's usually a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, it worked :)
I edited the question with the modified code.